# How does one compute the sin of the angle between subspaces in the Davis - Kahan theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The Davis Kahan theorem bounds the sin of the angle between subspaces spanned by eigenvectors under perturbation as follows:

$$
\||sin \Theta(A, B)\||_F \le \frac{\||\hat{\Sigma}-\Sigma\||_F}{\delta},
$$
where the right-hand side numerator gives the perturbation, its denominator $\delta$ is the eigengapm. $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ are the original and perturbed matrices, and $A$ and $B$ are the subspaces spanned by columns of the original and perturbed eigenvectors.

I'm interested in testing this empirically, but it's not clear to me how to actually compute the quantity on the right hand side. How would I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U_{A}$ and $U_{B}$ be matrices whose columns form an orthonormal basis for the corresponding eigenspaces.

We have that

$$
\lVert \sin \Theta(A, B) \rVert_{\mathsf{F}} = \lVert (I - U_A {U_A}^{\mathsf{T}}) U_B \rVert_{\mathsf{F}} =
\lVert (I - U_B {U_B}^{\mathsf{T}}) U_A \rVert_{\mathsf{F}}.
$$

For a formal proof, see Lemma 2.5 in [Spectral Methods for Data Science](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.08496).